# Mockito test returning NullInsteadOfMockException

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am trying to test my servlet for login page but the Mock test is throwing an exception

LoginServlet

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LoginServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    boolean result = false;
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    result = obj.validateLogin(username, password);
    if (result) {
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
        response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

    }
    return;
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

MockTest :  this is the test case I have written for login

```
public class LoginServletMockTest {

@Test
public void testServlet() throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    when(request.getParameter("username")).thenReturn("garwitauday");
    when(request.getParameter("password")).thenReturn("123");
    when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);

    doNothing().when(session).setAttribute("username", "garwitauday");
    doNothing().when(response).sendRedirect("Userhome.jsp");

    LoginServlet loginservlet = new LoginServlet();
    loginservlet.doPost(request, response);

    verify(session).setAttribute("username", "garwitauday");
    verify(response).sendRedirect("Userhome.jsp");

}

}
```

I am not able to resolve this issue

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Create the  mockito object for HttpSession also and set the mockito session object in request.

And continue your same do(..).when(..) or when(..).thenReturn(..) to mock the calls.

Make sure to set the attributes and parameters in request and session objects for easy testing.

If your's is mvc based servet, better to use MockMvc and it's builder objects.